Aligning domain model to data model. Is my data representation wrong?
Engineering Community,
I am currently writing my bachelor's thesis on microservices and DDD (this is not the actual topic, but it is part of it). The language I am writing in is Rust, but that is besides the point.
The issue I am currently facing is this: How do you handle domain-to-database mapping when your domain model doesn’t naturally include the information required by the database schema?
Picture this:
I have a domain model 'Order' (the context is an online shop) which looks roughly like so
struct Order {
  id: OrderId,
  metadata: Metadata,
  items: Vec<OrderItem>,
}

The domain model for Metadata looks like this:
struct Metadata {
  id: MetadataId,
  username: Username,
  //... more fields
}

The important thing being, that my Metadata domain model does not have a reference to its order.
This is where I struggle:
My SQL representation differs from the domain model
CREATE TABLE metadata (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    order_id UUID NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    username TEXT,
    -- snipped for brevity
    
    CONSTRAINT fk_metadata_order FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES orders (id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

Here the Metadata table actually references the table orders.
What I struggle with is, how do I properly map my domain model to my database representation, since I need to get the OrderId from somewhere.
CreateMetadataEntity::from_domain(metadata: Metadata, order_id: OrderId)
just doesn't feel great, because I always need to pass the ID seperately around my services - but at the same time I don't have a better idea!
I was wondering if there is a common approach to this sort of issue, or if my data (or domain) model is just wrong.
Have you encountered similar challenges when working with domain models and relational databases? What strategies worked for you?
Any advice would be highly appreciated!
Thanks :)

Everyone always struggles mapping domain models onto relational database models. Since this is a study project, consider looking into alternatives such as event sourcing with CQRS.

If you're never really going to need the metadata in isolation, treat the Order as an aggregate, and just have a save_order method on your repo that accepts a (domain layer) Order instance (which itself has a Metadata instance), and then transform your data and store both. Same when loading, but in reverse (and you probably want to load a number of objects based on some query, not just one).

Why does your metadata table even have its own id? Get rid of that, store your metadata under the order_id only.

@Bergi that is a valid point and I'll do that - however the issue still persists unless Metadata (I actually ended up changing the name to OrderDetails, because it seemed more appropriate) takes care of the ID-creation, right?

@RikD I will definitely consider this another time. However, CQRS is beyond the scope of what I want to achieve and sadly, deadline-wise doesn't seem feasible to me.

sometimes i think there is just one user that downvotes everything?

@Hannes The issue persists, yes, if you don't want the order_id to be part of the OrderDetails. Steve has already pointed out some potential solutions to that.

@Bergi I ended up dropping the orders table altogether and now just have an order_details and order_item table. I realized that the persistence model can differ from the root aggregate as long as a valid RA can be constructed from it — is that a correct observation? :)
Now, I’ve moved OrderId into OrderDetails (formerly Metadata). To reconstitute an Order, I fetch an OrderDetailsEntity and one or more  OrderItem entities from the database, call into_domain() on them, and construct the Order from there.
This feels much better than before!
Is this a valid approach?

@Hannes Yes, absolutely - I think this was also suggested below. Only thing I'd change is name the table order.

@Hannes, it's very common to call the pair of tables OrderHead/OrderLine, or just Order/OrderLine. One thing to get used to with designing SQL schemas is that a primary reason for splitting things across tables is to cope with the cardinality of the data - so there's nothing wrong in principle with placing what may seem like conceptually disjoint data about the order all in the head table, provided you only need to store one value per head. Using tables to conceptually group fields is not impermissible, but you don't do it as liberally as you might with client-side objects. (1/2)

So you don't need to worry about an all-encompassing name - it's accepted that the head table will contain a mixed bag of fields relating to the order and for which there is one value stored per order. Also, when tables are split, it's often because there are dozens of additional and lesser used fields which would contribute considerable clutter to the normal use of the main table. Or it's because there is a specific performance reason - as a table defines the physical colocation of data, so you can concentrate the heavily used data in one table and move the less used stuff out. (2/2)

@Steve this is something I will keep in mind! I took a Database class in my 2nd semester of university, but my SQL skills could ... use improvement, and that's putting it lightly. I think I really need to lose the tendency to structure my tables in the same way I would represent my objects in code, since SQL - as you said - just doesn't work that way. :')

The domain comes first

when your domain model doesn’t naturally include the information required by the database schema?

If your database exists to persist the data from your domain, and the database requires information that is undiscernible from the domain, then the database has introduced constraints that it should not have, and therefore your database schema is either wrong, or it should be responsible for handling its own bells and whistles that it chose to add to the data from the domain.
Let's use an analogy. I'm a baker. I bake bread. I hire you as the warehouse manager to store all the bread I bake. When I give you my bread to store, you tell me that I did it wrong because the bread does not contain an inbuilt NFC tag because that's how you chose to store things in the bread warehouse. Without that tag, you can't store the bread for later retrieval.
The outcome of that story will be that I fire you for not doing the job I hired you to do. I'm not going to be putting NFC tags in my bread. This is my company, I'm the boss, and you were hired to slot into how things worked around here.
It would've been okay if you had implemented a system where you e.g. wrap the bread in a bag with an NFC tag. And then when I asked you to retrieve the bread, you use your NFC solution, get the bags, take the bread out of the bags, and give me back my bread. What you do inbetween me giving you the bread and me asking you to give me my bread back is up to you to figure out and implement, that is what I hired you for.
You're doing a course on DDD. DDD is, by its very definition, domain-driven. In practicality, what this means is that the domain calls the shots. If the domain did not model a specific data point, therefore it is not a relevant data point to the domain, and it will not implement it just because others want it to (because the domain does not depend on anything else - you'll have heard this in your DDD course).

my Metadata domain model does not have a reference to its order


the Metadata table actually references the table orders

That FK constraint is the equivalent of the NFC tag in my analogy. The domain does not model a relationship here. It's not interested in that. It will never figure out the relationship, nor will it spend any time and effort to do so for others.
So what drove your persistence layer to decide that there should be a relationship here?
One possible outcome here whenever you deal with this kind of conflict in general is that the relationship just isn't necessary. That's not the outcome in this scenario, but I'm pointing it out for future reference when dealing with this.

An aggregate is an indivisible unit
As part of your DDD course, you would have come across aggregates (or aggregate roots). This is very important for the continuation of this answer - brush up on it if you need.
struct Order {
  id: OrderId,
  metadata: Metadata,
  items: Vec<OrderItem>,
}

By virtue of you stating in your data model that metadata must have a referenced order ID, you are implying that Metadata is not an aggregate on its own; it is a subaggregate that falls under the Order aggregate root.
Aggregate roots are, as far as DDD is concerned, an indivisible unit. Its subaggregates are not capable of existing on their own. Therefore, you should be passing your Order to the persistence layer, not the Metadata on its own.
This is the part where you have to make a decision on doing pure DDD or being pragmatic about it.
Pure DDD will tell you that you only store/retrieve the whole aggregate root. That is to say that there should only be a void SaveOrder(Order o) and Order GetOrder(id) method, the persistence layer should not be handling Metadata in isolation (as far as the public contract of the persistence layer is concerned - what happens internally is a different topic).
Pragmatically, you might have realistic expectations of not always loading metadata due to bandwidth/performance/memory concerns. This is off the beaten track as far as DDD goes, but that doesn't mean it's not allowable, you're just not going to find the answer to that in a DDD guide.
In such a case, you might actually decide that your persistence layer should fetch metadata separately. Metadata GetMetadata(orderId) is easy enough to design. But for the storage process, you should still be using your aggregate root, i.e. void SaveMetadata(Order o). While this method will only be saving the Metadata subaggregate of the Order, it's still important that you pass the entire order because, as established before, subaggregates cannot meaningfully/productively exist without the context of their aggregate root.
Whether you lean into pure DDD or a pragmatic balance depends on both your style, opinion, and whether you actually have performance considerations to balance here or not. If this example is purely done for the sake of DDD coursework, it may be better to stick to purism simply because that's the focus of the exercise.
In real world business development, however, purism is rarely the answer and a pragmatic approach tends to give you the better outcome.

If the link between order data and metadata is 1-to-1, then you could in fact move the foreign key to the order side (so that the order has a foreign key to the metadata, rather than the other way around). But you'd lose the automatic cascading update, and anyway I would say this would end up in a non-conventional arrangement - usually detail records have a foreign key to the master record, not the master having a foreign key to the details.
The basic issue is that in OO languages, a reference has a specific directionality because of the way the dereference operator works. SQL doesn't have a strict directionality, but to the extent it has any directionality at all, it runs in the opposite direction, due to the way joins and other database facilities work.
Another suggestion could be to move all the metadata fields themselves into the main order record, and abolish the separate table. So there might be two objects on the client-side, but in the database they are one row in one table. It's a complicated judgement whether this is the best solution for a particular case. Or you also could collapse the two objects into one, to match the one table - so an order object, incorporating metadata, would map to a single order table which incorporates the metadata fields.
Finally, you may just have to accept that each layer of the overall program is organising data in different ways for good reasons local to each layer, and you'll manually have to move the reference/foreign key from one side to the other. I would say this is the best and most flexible course of action in general, and should be the default approach.
As an aside, I've just been having big arguments over at LangDev about the general differences between how SQL and OO languages work, and your example here illustrates a very interesting difference about which side the pointer/foreign key get stored on, so thanks from me to you for that!

Thank you for the insight - I'm glad this was useful to you in some way.
So what I'm getting is, that as always, there's no silver bullet here?
In a sense I am glad that I didn't just overlook the obvious - but I admit, I was hoping for a nifty trick or pattern to make this cleaner.
Thanks again for the proposed solutions!

Nope. There is no silver bullet. This is hard no matter which language and tech stack you use. Relational data models are good at storing data consistently. Object oriented languages model behavior, not data. They solve different problems and seem to be fundamentally at odds with one another.

I'm probably missing something. Why would cascades break for the first option?

@donnih, no, there's no silver bullet and no error on your part. Data structures on the client-side often don't align with the database schema anyway, because you'll need ways to represent structures created by non-trivial queries (i.e. not just those which call data in a very simple way from base tables, but have a complicated mix and calculated fields, etc.), and you might also adopt data structures that are specially designed for high performance when matched with certain algorithms. So although the object-to-row mapping looks like a near-miss in simple cases, it isn't when you get going.

@Basilevs, on second thought you're right. If the FK field is moved to the order, and you delete the order, you're deleting the foreign side but leaving the primary side untouched - that was as far as my thinking went. But there's nothing to stop the FK being defined in the other direction, with the PK for metadata now in the order table, and order still treated as the primary side and metadata as the foreign/secondary side. (1/2)

If you got that far though, I suppose you'd purge the separate PK for metadata entirely, and just reuse the order PK as both the PK and FK on the metadata side. I.e. you'd have order(order_id PK, ...) and metadata(order_id PK FK, ...). I think I'd want to do something about the naming scheme in this case. But definitely point well made. (2/2)

That might be the approach I'm going to end up using, haven't thought about that one yet. Since each order has exactly one related "metadata" - I might as well reuse the PK from my order as the PK for metadata! (1/2)

Though on second thought the issue here would be that I need a Metadata instance to construct my Order domain model - but to construct a Metadata model I need the ID for the related order.
The obvious solution to me would be, that Metadata constructs the ID and Order just reuses the one that Metadata has constructed - but I feel like this approach pushes the responsibility for ID generation onto Metadata, which doesn’t align well with the idea that Order is the aggregate root in this context.

@donnih, yes I sense some kind of potential to have trouble with the generation of IDs under certain circumstances. My recommendation would be to first follow the conventional (and most general) approach that each table allocates its own unique IDs for its rows, and that foreign key fields go on the secondary side not the primary side (if you're following what I mean by primary/secondary in this context). (1/2)

And don't allow the database design to be twisted around this observation about how references/memory pointers work on the client-side. There can be a large number of different ways to model the same thing on a case-by-case basis, but the limiting factor is really the need for consistency for the developer, and to avoid unnecessary variety and surprise. (2/2)

Domain Models are not persisted. Aggregate Roots are persisted.
In this case, if the AR is the Order, then you are saving the Order with the Metadata, have access to the orderId and can have whatever table structure you want.
using FKs and cascade functions on the database make sense, as you are always going to be taking actions on the whole AR, so these relationships can be part of the datalayer.
eg
OrderRepo.Save(Order order) {
   sql = "insert into order values (order.Id, order....)
   ...
   sql = "insert into metadata (id, orderid) values ({order.MetaData.Id}, {order.OrderId})
   ...
}

If both Order and Metadata are their own ARs then you have to allow for the idea of more than one thing referencing the same Metadata. If you do, then you cant put orderId int the Metadata table, as that would misrepresent the relationships.
Also, you can't have the FKs and auto cascade delete etc as this would delete Metadata which is still potentially referenced by some other Domain Model. The datalayer mustn't add logic that's not part of the Domain Model.
But you can put MetaDataId in the Order table and allow for orphaned and missing Metadata

Sorry, I used confusing language. Order is the AR here and will be persisted. A more fitting name for Metadata would actually be OrderDetails, so it is definitely heavily tied to the Order AR.

Are we using the term differently? if the Order is an AR and includes the Meta data, then when you save you dont have the problem you describe because you can just use the orderId from the order to insert to the metadata table?

added an example
